# System.Object[] instead of the actual path in the array

Tags: powershell, csv

The script below does not produce the path to the files in question, in my CSV file.  Instead it is giving me System.Object[].  Please advise as to what I am doing wrong here.

My goal is to clean up redundant GPO's. I need to search the xml files from a GPO backup and analyze them. If I find the same custom string in two or more GPO's, the path will show me which folder contains the redundant string and can either combine the GPO's or delete one all together. Makes sense .. I hope?
  Here are the results I get :The first is the count, The third row is the value of that line and the 2nd row is the System.Object which should show the path like

> c:\gpobackup\00A72CC5-7935-4F97-A40B-68DE0ED927BF
>
> 1  System.Object[] Identifier xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">{548FF13C-4CDD-43C7-8C59-D19087424B16}
>       5 System.Object[]     Domain xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">corp.domain.net
>       5 System.Object[]   
>        1  System.Object[]   Name>Exchange Move - SNY SPA - enable PST archiving
>        5  System.Object[]   IncludeComments>true

```
$ht = @()
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml
    foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $path = $file.FullName
    $lines = Get-Content $path
    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
         if ($match = $ht | where { $_.line -EQ $line })
         {
            $match.count = $match.count + 1
            $match.Paths += $path
         }
        else
        {
            $ht += new-object PSObject -Property @{
                Count = 1
                Paths = @(, $path)
                Line = $line
            }
        }
    }
}

$ht
$ht.GetEnumerator() | select Count, Paths, Line | Export-Csv c:\temp\NLG_GPO_Sort.csv
```

Comment: Your script isn't really taking advantage of PowerShell's pipeline behavior. What is the end goal of the script? We can probably redesign it to work more efficiently.

Comment: @Bill  My goal is to clean up redundant GPO's.  I need to search the xml files from a GPO backup and analyze them.  If I find the same custom string in two or more GPO's, the path will show me which folder contains the redundant string and can either combine the GPO's or delete one all together.  Makes sense .. I hope?

Comment: It would help if you could post sample file content as well as the output you're expecting.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I added examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Export-Csv` doesn't magically expand properties with array values. You need to do that yourself:

```psh
$ht.GetEnumerator() |
  select Count, @{n='Paths';e={$_.Paths -join '|'}}, Line |
  Export-Csv c:\temp\NLG_GPO_Sort.csv
```

Comment: @Ken That's most likely because the code evaluating the content of each file adds the path for each matching line. You shouldn't process XML files like that anyway. Identify the criteria (values, attributes) that constitute a matching GPO and use an XML parser to check those criteria. However, that would be a different question, so you should post it as a new one. A quick and dirty workaround (which I do not recommend) would be to select the unique paths: `@{n='Paths';e={($_.Paths | select -Unique) -join '|'}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ansgar.  I will post a different question.